# Battle star rating effect on drops in FFXII-2

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Is there only an effect on drop rates in final fantasy XIII-2 with 5 stars?

You just see an increase listed with 5 stars but I thought there may possibly be an alternate effect for stars 1 through 4.

Answer (score 3):

If you get 5 stars in a battle it increases your drop rate by 200%. Anything below this doesn't affect natural drop rate of a battle.

However, you can equip a `Collector's Catalog` which can be won from Chocobo Racing in `Serendipity` which increases your drop rate by 20%.

There is also the `Durable Catalog` which increases drop rates even more (120% for a rare drop and 300% for normal item drop) and you can also use a `Silver Chocobo` which will have `Item Scavenger 2' which increases item drop rate by 150%.

**These aren't stackable though:** meaning your best option is to get the `Durable Catalog`

Comment: Incidentally, once I started using them, I put a Durable Catalog on both Serah and Noel.  I was pretty sure they didn't stack (drop percentages didn't increase), but I left them on.  Beat all the hardest bosses that way.  Do NOT like the Proto-Behemoth.

Comment: @fbueckert You can't even stack with Silver Chocobo + Durable Catalog :(

Comment: Apotamkin also has `Item Scavenger` but he must be present at the end of the battle for it to take effect. So the same for the Silver Chocobo.

Comment: Does the 5 star bonus stack with other bonuses?

Comment: @kotekzot I believe they are yes.

Comment: Just to confirm the maths. I have Durable Collector Catalog on both Serah and Noel, and Apotempkin. I got rare 350% and normal 500%

Answer (score 0):

I have the DLC Valhalla Lightning Lv.13 with Gilfinder II, Item Collector, Item Scavenger II.

Item Collector: Increases the odds of obtaining rare items after battle.

Item Scavenger II:Increases the odds of obtaining items after battle.

Gilfinder II: Increases gil earned after battle.

She is basically another Collector Catalog.

Lightning in party with Noel and Serah both wearing the Durable Collector Catalog all the gilfinders stack so you will get a lot of cash.

Not sure about the items though.