# Where to find Collectors Catalog?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I've now completed the story in FF13-2 and am starting to get stuck into the 'extra' bits.

It seems that I need two collectors catalog items to help me farm better items. I'd like to get them so I can farm lv4 bio monster mats quicker.

I think you win it in Chocobo racing, but I've never seen it as a reward, am I doing something wrong?

I tried up to Fal'Cie class with my max level gold chocobo and never saw it. I wasted so many casino coins on shuffle items :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually get a `Collectors Catalog` from Chocobo Racing but Chocobo racing is actually required to obtain it. Follow these steps, but I warn you, it is a long and arduous task:

1. Acquire a `Golden Chocobo` from 'A Dying World - 700AF'. It's found in a dead-end somewhere. (You've already done this, but so others know).
2. Max-out this Chocobo's stats. I think the max is level 45.
3. Go mental. Race at the Chocobo Arena until you reach `Fal'cie` class.
4. Keep an eye out for the race `Dahaka's Stake`. This race sometimes gives the item `Collector's Catalog`. You can use items ( I forget which ) to refresh the items rewarded from this race.

**OPTIONAL: This will max out a Collector's Catalog**

5. Obtain one `Collector's Catalogs` from step 4 above.
6. Obtain two `Pheonix Bloods`. If you don't have some already in your inventory then they can be bought for 1600 chips at the `Casino`, which you should have amassed from your racing anyway.
7. Obtain two `Sunpetals`. These are dropped in windy `Archylytte Steppe` from the Microchu but these are a **rare drop**
8. Go to see `Chocolina` at the Archlytte Steppe and you can buy a `Durable Collectors Catalog` for 40,000 gil a piece.
9. Enjoy your upgraded Durable Collectors Catalogs which increase item drop, gil etc etc

Ah yes, they're not stackable see my answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55356/battle-star-rating-effect-on-drops-in-ffxii-2/55363#55363) to see details on drop rate improvement from accessories / abilities

Comment: So it's just this single race that I need? Do I have to shuffle loads in order to get it to show up? Do I want the regular shuffle item or the 'graded' shuffle?

Comment: Pretty sure they don't stack.

Comment: @DavidYell You can use either, but statistically speaking it would be more likely with the `Graded Shuffle`

Comment: @fbueckert I thought so, I was 100% sure I'd answered a question saying as much and had the exact percentages for what each does, alas I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Chocobo races. You get to a certain level and you'll find it. Races are in Serendipity. Best chocobo is golden chocobo.